# How to Plot square, rectangular, hex 2D surface using array method instead of 'for loop'?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am looking for general code which plot square, rectangular, hexagon 2D surface, using initial 2x2 matrix.

Following is the code I wanted to eliminate'for loop' and instead use simpler array method using numpy. In the bigger picture, I have 8 'for loop' which will slow down my program significantly.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


l= 10 #loop limits
lmit=5#plot limits

# 2x2 matrix
a = [-0.5, 1];
b = [1.00, 0.00];

# variable define
x = np.zeros((2*l, 2*l))
y = np.zeros((2*l, 2*l))

fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(-l, l):
    for k in range(-l, l):
        x[i + l, k + l] = (i * a[0] + k * b[0]);
        y[i + l, k + l] = (i * a[1] + k * b[1]);
        plt.scatter(x[i + l, k + l], y[i + l, k + l], s=6, color='Blue')


plt.ylim(-lmit, lmit)
plt.xlim(-lmit, lmit)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For a start does one plot command outside the loop work? `plt.scatter(x, y, s=6, color='Blue')`.  That is plot the whole arrays with one call rather than one point at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a [`meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and make use of numpy's [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). (Note that in Python, lines shouldn't end with a semicolon, except sometimes the very last command in a Jupyter block.)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = 10  # loop limits

# 2x2 matrix
a = [-0.5, 1]
b = [1.00, 0.00]

x0, y0 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-l, l + 1), np.arange(-l, l + 1))
x1 = x0 * a[0] + y0 * b[0]
y1 = x0 * a[1] + y0 * b[1]

plt.scatter(x1, y1, s=6, color='navy')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]